# What does "couldn't drink water fast enough" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *The Wolf of Wall Street* (2013), Manny advised Jordan Belfort to pay a million dollar fine for stock
manipulation, walk away from Stratton Oakmont, and put Donnie in charge
so that the SEC and Agent Denham wouldn’t pursue him ever again, but
Jordan Belfort didn’t follow the advice:

> Jordan Belfort: Within days, subpoenas started flying.  Notices to
> produce documents, depositions, you name it. Donnie **couldn't drink
> water fast enough**.

What does "couldn't drink water fast enough" mean?

Comment: In context, something to do with 'watered' (fraudulently issued) stock, I suspect.

Comment: You should ask "What does it **mean**?", not _means_.

Comment: @KateBunting Done.

Comment: Is there any reason to suppose that it is not literal?  "Donnie was unable to imbibe H₂O at a high enough rate"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Donnie pisses on a subpoena, to applause".

> 202H INT. STRATTON OAKMONT III - JORDAN'S OFFICE - DAY 202H (SPRING ‘96)
> .
> Janet enters Jordan's office, leaves a stack of legal papers on his desk.
>
> JORDAN (V.O.) Within days, subpoenas started flying. They were burying me in paper --
>
> 202Ha INT. STRATTON OAKMONT III - BULLPEN - DAY (SPRING ‘96) 202Ha
> Donnie pisses on a subpoena, to applause.
>
> JORDAN (V.O.)
> -- notices to produce documents, depositions. Donnie couldn't drink water fast enough.

https://lyrics.az/martin-scorsese/-/the-wolf-of-wall-street-screenplay.html

In order to be able to continue his show of bravado, he has to drink a lot of water, as many legal notices were arriving.

Comment: Interesting how may water-related expressions there are in finance. One can _take a bath_ with investments, a company needs to _wash its face_. Probably more.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a symbolic way of expressing that I could not meet a demand or relieve a condition quickly enough to keep up with the pace at which it was needed or happening. Or we can say this expression can be applied to situations where efforts to address a problem, fulfill a need, or keep up with something are overwhelmed by the speed or intensity of the situation.

Comment: Yes, all the activity was dehydrating him.